# How can I read Excel file into List<Map<String, String>>

Tags: java, apache-poi

How can I read excel file into `List<Map<String, String>>`, where first I need to get column names from excel, then to get all values and put it into `List<Map<String, String>>`. I want to get a some value from this collection like this: `String columnValue = map.get("column_name");`

Comment: So what is the problem that you are facing?

Answer (score -1):

You can export the data from excel in CSV format and use Apache's CSV parser library for JAVA.

And then after importing the library in your classpath you can simply use it as

```
Reader in = new FileReader("path/to/file.csv");
Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.EXCEL.parse(in);
for (CSVRecord record : records) {
    String lastName = record.get("Last Name");
    String firstName = record.get("First Name");

}
```

After this you can store data in your List in desired way.

For more information look into 
[https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/index.html](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/user-guide.html)

Comment: If you read my answer I mentioned that if the OP exports data from Excel to CSV.